# Splitting up Vuex store into separate files gives commit false

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using `Vuex` in `Vue.js`.

First, if I put my store inside the main.js. It worked.

But when I split my store into a file called store.js it is not working.

src/store.js

src/main.js

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'Vue'
import Vuex from 'Vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    title: 'Hello from the Vuex Store',
  }
});
```

**main.js**

```
import { store } from './store.js';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
)};
```

I tried to `console.log(store)`

and I got a commit false, that is why I know it is not working. 
Anything else is correct so I do not include in the codes.

Here is a screenshot of what I console.log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT0lu.png)

Comment: Where in your code you log the vuex's state? `main.js` doesn't contain `console.log`.

Comment: I said I just tried to console.log(store) to see what happened and why it is not working.

Comment: main.js is a javascript file. Why can't I console.log?

Comment: If you're trying to access your state use `console.log(this.$store.state.title);`

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way instead it has worked for me in the past.

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'Vue'
import Vuex from 'Vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

window.store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
     title: 'Hello from the Vuex Store',
  }
});
```

**main.js**

```
require('store.js');

let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow magically, I needed to add:

```
import Vuex from 'Vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex);
```

in the main.js for Vuex to work. Anyway, I hope this question helps someone else who is a beginner of Vuex.

Comment: Not magic, literally the fourth call out (first for modular support) under the installation instructions of vuex. https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html